# Flutter Riverpod, FutureProvider stuck at AsyncLoading<>

Tags: flutter, riverpod, dio

I am using DropDownSearch package and there are 3 dropdown search field.
At first I load data into these 3 fields from a single api.
after that, based on the selected item at the first dropdown field, i want to fetch another api and show the result in second Drop down field. everytime the selected item changes i want to get its corresponding value from api. I did it this way, but after implementing the second api, the Future provider keeps loading and gives AsyncLoading<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9GF2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAPkS.png)

Here is my code:

```
class ReportPageView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReportPageView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    GetListModel modelRef = GetListModel();
    modelRef.refName = 'AccountLedgerReport';
    modelRef.isSingleList = 'false';
    modelRef.singleListNameStr = '';
    modelRef.listNameId = "['underGroup', 'mainLedger-${1}', 'mainBranch-${2}']";
    modelRef.mainInfoModel = mainInfo;
    modelRef.conditionalValues = '';


    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        final outCome = ref.watch(listProvider(modelRef));
        print('data fetched again');
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: outCome.when(
              data: (data) {
                final mData = ref.watch(setListProvider);
              

                List<String> groups = [];
                List<String> ledgers = [];
                List<String> branches = [];

                data[0].forEach((key, _) {
                  groups.add(key);
                });
                data[1].forEach((key, _) {
                  ledgers.add(key);
                });
                data[2].forEach((key, _) {
                  branches.add(key);
                });
                
                String ledgerItem = ledgers[0];
                String branchItem = branches[0];

                final nData = ref.watch(itemProvider).test;
                return SafeArea(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 350,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                DropdownSearch<String>(
                                  items: groups,
                                  selectedItem: nData,
                                  onChanged: (dynamic value) async {
                                    ref.read(itemProvider.notifier).changeText(value);
                                   
                                  },
                                ),
                                const Spacer(),
                                nData == 'Accumulated Amortization' ? DropdownSearch<String>(
                                  items: ledgers,
                                  selectedItem: ledgerItem,
                                ) :
                                Consumer(
                                  builder: (context, ref, child) {
                                    GetListModel ledgerGroupListModel = GetListModel();
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.refName = 'AccountLedgerReport';
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.isSingleList = 'true';
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.singleListNameStr = 'account';
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.listNameId = "['mainLedger-${35}']";
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.mainInfoModel = mainInfo;
                                    ledgerGroupListModel.conditionalValues = '';

                                    final newData = ref.watch(ledgerItemProvider(ledgerGroupListModel));
                                    return newData.when(
                                      data: (data) {
                                        List<String> uLedgerItem = [];
                                        data.forEach((key,_) {
                                          uLedgerItem.add(key);
                                        });
                                        return DropdownSearch<String>(
                                          items: uLedgerItem,
                                         
                                        );
                                      },
                                      error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('$error'),
                                      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                                const Spacer(),
                                DropdownSearch<String>(
                                  items: branches,
                                  selectedItem: branchItem,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    branchItem = value!;
                                    print('selected changed');
                                  },
                                ),
                                const Spacer(),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {},
                                 
                                  child: const FaIcon(
                                    FontAwesomeIcons.arrowsRotate,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                   
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                       
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              error: (error, stackTrace) => Center(child: Text('$error'),),
              loading: () {
                return const SpinKitFoldingCube(
                  color: Color(0xffFD872A),
                  size: 30,
                );
              },
            )
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Providers:

```
final listProvider = FutureProvider.family.autoDispose((ref, GetListModel model) => ListProvider().getMenu(model));

class ListProvider{
  Future<List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>> getMenu(GetListModel getListModel) async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final jsonData = jsonEncode(getListModel.toJson());
    List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> myList = [];
    try{
      final response = await dio.post(Api.getList, data: jsonData);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        final responseList = response.data as List<dynamic>;
        var group = {};
        var ledger = {};
        var branch = {};

        for(final e in responseList[0]){
          group[ListModel.fromJson(e).text!] = ListModel.fromJson(e).value!;
        }
        for(final e in responseList[1]){
          ledger[ListModel.fromJson(e).text!] = ListModel.fromJson(e).value!;
        }
        for(final e in responseList[2]){
          branch[ListModel.fromJson(e).text!] = ListModel.fromJson(e).value!;
        }
        myList = [group, ledger, branch];
      }else{
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
      return myList;
    }on DioError catch(err){
      throw DioException().getDioError(err);
    }
  }
}

final ledgerItemProvider = FutureProvider.family((ref, GetListModel model) => LedgerProvider().getLedgerItem(model));

class LedgerProvider{
  Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> getLedgerItem(GetListModel getListModel) async {
    final dio = Dio();
    final jsonData = jsonEncode(getListModel.toJson());
    var ledger = {};
    try{
      final response = await dio.post(Api.getList, data: jsonData);
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        final responseList = response.data as List<dynamic>;
        for(final e in responseList[0]){
          ledger[ListModel.fromJson(e).text!] = ListModel.fromJson(e).value!;
        }
      }else{
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
      return ledger;
    }on DioError catch(err){
      throw DioException().getDioError(err);
    }
  }
}


final itemProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => GroupItem());

class GroupItem extends ChangeNotifier{
  String test = 'Accumulated Amortization';


  void changeText(String text){
    test = text;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to fetch the api every time the selected item value in the (Group) DropDownSearch changes.

Comment: try with  extending  consumer state

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin can you please elaborate?

Comment: Update: I dont understand why and how but the problem was gone when i moved the ledgerGroupListModel (instance of GetListModel) out of the inner consumer to inside the first first consumer.